# Why doesn't AutoMapper map these nested collections?

Tags: c#, vb.net, automapper

I have the following source classes in VB.

```
Public Class Product
...

    Public Property itemizedSize As Size()
        Get
            Return _arrItemizedSizes
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Size())
            _arrItemizedSizes = value
        End Set
    End Property
...
End Class


Public Class Size
    Private _strName As String
    Private _intQuantity As Integer
    Private _intScale As Integer

    Public Property name() As String
        Get
            Return _strName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _strName = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property quantity() As Integer
        Get
            Return _intQuantity
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _intQuantity = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Scale() As Integer
        Get
            Return _intScale
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _intScale = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New()
        _strName = ""
        _intQuantity = 0
        _intScale = 0
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal name As String, ByVal quantity As Integer, Optional ByVal Scale As Integer = 0)
        _strName = name
        _intQuantity = quantity
        _intScale = Scale
    End Sub
End Class
```

and I am trying to map it to these C# classes

```
public class ProductsViewModel : List<ProductViewModel>
{
    ...
}

public class ProductViewModel
{
    ...
    public SizeViewModel[] ItemizedSize { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class SizeViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

I am using the following code to do my mapping... however, I get an exception saying that a mapping is not defined from Size to SizeViewModel

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Size, SizeViewModel>();
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Product, ProductViewModel>();

ProductsViewModel model = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<List<Product>, ProductsViewModel>(productDetails);
AutoMapper.Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

Is there something that I am missing? Any help would be much appreciated.. thanks!

Comment: .net has class Size. change the name of your class. maybe it works.

Comment: Good spot - hover over that Size in VS and see what namespace you are getting... automapper doesn't care what types get mapped, but you do :)

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that... it is the Size class in my namespace

Answer (score 0):

I just ran your code and everything works perfectly for me.  What version of AutoMapper are you using?  I'm using version 2.0.0.0.

Here is my VB code:

```
Public Class Product


    Public Property itemizedSize As Size()
        Get
            Return _arrItemizedSizes
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Size())
            _arrItemizedSizes = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Property _arrItemizedSizes As Size()

End Class


Public Class Size
    Private _strName As String
    Private _intQuantity As Integer
    Private _intScale As Integer

    Public Property name() As String
        Get
            Return _strName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _strName = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property quantity() As Integer
        Get
            Return _intQuantity
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _intQuantity = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Scale() As Integer
        Get
            Return _intScale
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _intScale = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New()
        _strName = ""
        _intQuantity = 0
        _intScale = 0
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal name As String, ByVal quantity As Integer, Optional ByVal Scale As Integer = 0)
        _strName = name
        _intQuantity = quantity
        _intScale = Scale
    End Sub
End Class
```

Here is the C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using SimpleLib;  //That is the VB assembly

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class ProductsViewModel : List<ProductViewModel>
    {

    }

    public class ProductViewModel
    {
        public SizeViewModel[] ItemizedSize { get; set; }
    }

    public class SizeViewModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.Name + " " + this.Quantity.ToString();
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Size, SizeViewModel>();
            AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Product, ProductViewModel>();

            List<Product> productDetails = new List<Product>()
                                               {
                                                   new Product() {itemizedSize = new Size[1] {new Size("hello", 2, 5)}},
                                                   new Product() {itemizedSize = new Size[1] {new Size("hello2", 4, 10)}}
                                               };

            ProductsViewModel model = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<List<Product>, ProductsViewModel>(productDetails);
            AutoMapper.Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

            Console.WriteLine("Count: {0}", model.Count);
            Console.WriteLine("First Product: {0}", model[0].ItemizedSize[0].ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Second Product: {0}", model[1].ItemizedSize[0].ToString());

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm using a console app to test it.  I get everything mapping through correctly and no Configuration errors from AutoMapper.

This is the output I get:

```
Count: 2
First Product: hello 2
Second Product: hello2 4
```